# Eclipse console text colors for black theme hardly readable

Tags: eclipse

How in gods name can I change the color of these blue lines please?

[image]

I found

[image]

but that doesn't show the horrible blue color (well, horrible on a black background anyway).

Comment: Since that is the CDT Build console maybe there is something in the C/C++ preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Greg-449. That's it....

[image]